# Calculus Area Indefinite Integral

Tags: calculus

[image: can someone show me the evaluation step-by-step please]

I calculated the anti-derivative but plugging in for x is confusing.

can someone show me the evaluation step-by-step please

Comment: What is the antiderivative? If you have it, stick in $\ln 8 / 2$, and subtract what happens when you stick in $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_{[0, \log(8)/2]} e^{2x} - 8 \mathrm{d}x = \left[\frac{1}{2} e^{2x} - 8 x \right]_{x=0}^{x = \log(8)/2} \\ \hspace{67mm}= \underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{2} e^{\log(8)} - 4 \log 8 \right)}_{\text{Plugging in $x = \log(8)/2$}} - \underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{2} e^0 - 8\cdot 0 \right)}_{\text{Plugging in $x = 0$}} \\\hspace{20mm} = \frac{7}{2} - 4 \log(8)
$$

**EDIT:** This edit is to address your questions in the comments. It seems like perhaps you are simply have trouble with basic algebra, rather than calculus.

Here are some questions for you that if you solve, will finish all the algebra.

What is $2(\frac{\log(8)}{2})$, $8(\frac{\log(8)}{2})$? What about $e^0$? What about $e^{\log(8)}$? It is important that you can figure these things out!

Comment: Can u take things step by step like how did you get 4 log 8 and (1/2)^e log (8)

Comment: Anticipating : What is $\log$?  I thought we were dealing with $\ln$???

Comment: @ deven what about the 7/2

Comment: the answer is 4ln8 -(7/2) the signs are backwards

Comment: @Mike .. No it's not.

Comment: ....i think there was a mistake then maybe doing the limits the other way will get you the right answer

Comment: @Mike it's unclear what you mean "The right answer". The answer given is the correct answer to the integral you posted. But yes if you put the limits in the other direction you will get negative of this.

Answer (score 0):

The antiderivative is $\frac{1}{2}e^{2x} - 8x$.  Evaluating at the two endpoints gives $\frac{1}{2}e^{\ln8} - \frac{8}{2}\ln8 - \frac{1}{2}e^{0} = \frac{7}{2} - 4 \ln8$

Comment: how did you get the ln8 in the first exponent

Comment: @Mike $ 2 (\log(8)/2) = \log(8)$.

Comment: where is 7/2 coming from ?

Comment: @Mike $4 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{7}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

So, for the lower bound, we have $e^{0}/2 = 1/2$, and then for the upper bound $x=ln(8)/2$ we have $8 \; ln(8)/2 + e^{ln(8)}/2$ , which is equal to $4+12ln(2)$. You just subtract $1/2$ from this value to calculate the integral.